# i am having connecting the path for vue.js in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.

```
Vue.component('chat-app', require('./components/ChatApp.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: can you elaborate your problem mate? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: actually i am new to vue.js and i get errors in the browser like app.js:14216 GET http://localhost:8012/contacts 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:14216
xhrAdapter @ app.js:14050
dispatchRequest @ app.js:36149
Promise.then (async)

Comment: 404 (Not Found) means the page your trying to go is not found in your project. Please note that it is case sensitive, check your code.

Comment: how can i edit this path ????

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like we will need more information about what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried, and what specifically is going wrong. Writing a good quality question results in good quality answers :) Take a look at this for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask